# how can I serve external folder with twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

there is a captiveportal script in python that works with twisted but it load the portal page in the script (search CAPTIVE_TEMPLATE)

https://github.com/bendemott/captiveportal/blob/master/captiveportal

how can I load a full index.html folder with js and css and other material like docs and files with twisted?

best regards

Answer (score 3):

Use File and pass it a directory.

```
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.static import File
from twisted.internet import reactor

resource = File('/tmp')
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8888, factory)
reactor.run()
```

See more [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.1.0/web/howto/web-in-60/static-content.html)